# ¿Como se calcula el CheckSum (CkSum) en Java?

Tags: java, c#

Me gustaría saber como se calcular el Cksum en Java, anteriormente lo calculaba en C# con la siguiente función que encontré aquí.

```
    private string CalculaCksum(String hexString)
    {
        byte[] buf = SoapHexBinary.Parse(hexString).Value;

        int chkSum = buf.Aggregate(0, (s, b) => s += b) & 0xff;
        chkSum = (0x100 - chkSum) & 0xff;

        var str = chkSum.ToString("X2"); // <-- D9
        return str;
    }
```

Por ejemplo:

```
 String data = "0001000001";
 String cksum = CalculaCksum(data);
```

Donde data representan bytes hexadecimal a calcular el cksum. Es decir data como un arreglo de bytes sería de la siguiente manera:

```
 byte[] data = {0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01}
```

El resultado es del calculo es "FE", el problema es que no puedo utilizar esta función en Java.

Comment: Así es, son lenguajes parecidos pero no iguales. ¿Has intentado o buscado algo para portar tu código?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/implementing-checksum-using-java